# Is it possible to add a superscript trademark symbol to a menu?

Tags: menus

Is it possible to add a superscript trademark symbol to a WordPress menu?

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: Josh asked about displaying the trademark in "superscript" font, so I don't think this question has been answered. I too cannot display the TM symbol in superscript -- instead it's about the same size as the heading font, and at the baseline.

Comment: @Chad put it in a `<sup>` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use any HTML entities for the titles. I've put `&trade;` in menus before. You can also try the code: `&#8482;`

Comment: You can also put html entities in a superscript tag: `<sup>&trade;</sup>`